# Transcription problem with Google Cloud services

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I try to transcribe with Google Cloud using this method
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-console

I got stuck at this point
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-console#model_adaptation_optional
It does not let me send to create the transcript

Attaches a screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF5FW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit it for which you have to select Workspace from the dropdown option as can be seen in the image. A workspace is a Cloud Storage bucket that stores your Speech-to-Text assets, like configurations, uploaded audio files, and transcriptions. You can use an existing Cloud Storage bucket or you can create a new one.

[image]